# How to persist a dask dataframe loaded with dask.dataframe.from_delayed

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed

I have a large sharded dataset stored in a custom format that would benefit greatly from `dask.dataframe.from_delayed`

However, I'm seeing odd behavior when trying to persist the resulting dataframe:

```
def load(file):
  # Just an example...Actual loading code is more complex.
  return pd.read_parquet(file)

filenames = ['my_file']
df = dd.from_delayed([delayed(load)(f) for f in filenames])
df = df.persist()
print(df.count().compute())
```

This results in two consecutive 'load' tasks with each task loading data from the network from scratch: once when calling .persist() and once when running computations on the persisted dataframe.

I would expect only one 'load' task, and then the computations would work on the persisted dataframe.

I verified that

```
df = dd.read_parquet('my_file')
df = df.persist()
print(df.count().compute())
```

correctly only schedules one read_parquet task so data is only loaded from the network once.

Is there a workaround for this issue to ensure that after calling .persist, data isn't re-downloaded from the network?

Comment: "two consecutive 'load' tasks" - for every partition, or only the first one?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response...

...Interesting. I see different behavior if loading a single-partition dataset vs. a multi-partition.

For a single-partition dataset, I see two 'loads'. Judging from the duration of the tasks, each load looks like its downloading the dataset from the network.

For a n-partition dataset, I see one 'load' followed by n 'load-from-delayed' where each task is about the length of downloading a single partition.

Is this expected?

If I have a lot of computations to do on the df, what's the best way to ensure that data re-downloading is minimized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a dask dataframe, dask needs to know the columns and types, so that it can infer further lazy operations you might do on it. In `from_delayed`, you have an opportunity to provide this thing with the `meta=` argument. If you *don't* provide it, dask will load the first partition to infer it, and then discard that data - which can be costly as you say.

So, the answer is: provide `meta=`; either you can just know it, or else, find a way to load only a portion of the first partition to infer it at runtime.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense and matches what I see in the Dask dashboard.